# WinRT StorageFile write downloaded file

Tags: stream, download, windows-runtime, webresponse, storagefile

I'm struggling with a easy problem. I want to download an image from web using this code:

```
WebRequest requestPic = WebRequest.Create(@"http://something.com/" + id + ".jpg");
WebResponse responsePic = await requestPic.GetResponseAsync();
```

Now I wanted to write the WebResponse's stream in a StorageFile (eg. create a file id.jpg in the app's storage), but I haven't found any way to achieve that. I searched the web for it, but no success - all ways incompatible Stream types and so on.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found the following solution, which works and is not too complicated.

```
    public async static Task<StorageFile> SaveAsync(
        Uri fileUri,
        StorageFolder folder,
        string fileName)
    {
        var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
        var download = downloader.CreateDownload(
            fileUri,
            file);

        var res = await download.StartAsync();            

        return file;
    }
```

Comment: Great answer. Simple and it works perfectly. No more problems while reading "not complete" files. Thanks alot man.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to read the response stream into a buffer then write the data to a StorageFile. THe following code shows an example:

```
        var fStream = responsePic.GetResponseStream();
        var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("testfile.txt");
        using (var ostream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                var buffer = new byte[1024];
                count = fStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                await ostream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            while (fStream.CanRead && count > 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be done [using the C++ REST SDK in Windows Store Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn385707.aspx). It's explained by [HTTP Client Tutorial](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Http%20Client%20Tutorial).